# No implicit view available from K => Ordered[K]. Error occurred in an application involving default arguments

Tags: scala, class, generics, case, implicit

I'm trying to implement a set based on a weight-based tree in Scala. I have the following class hierarchy:

```
case class Node[K, V](key: K, value: Option[V] = None, left: Option[Node[K, V]] = None, right: Option[Node[K, V]] = None, size: Int = 1)(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])

case class Tree[K, V](root: Option[Node[K, V]] = None, alpha: Double = 0.25)(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])

case class WBTreeSet[K](tree: Tree[K, Nothing] = Tree[K, Nothing]())(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])
```

Classes get `Ordered[K]` implicitly so that I can compare elements of type K and build the tree.

When I try to compile the code, I get the following errors:

```
No implicit view available from K => Ordered[K].
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
case class WBTreeSet[K](tree: Tree[K, Nothing] = Tree[K, Nothing]())(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K]) {

not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])Tree[K,Nothing] in object Tree.
Unspecified value parameter ord.
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
case class WBTreeSet[K](tree: Tree[K, Nothing] = Tree[K, Nothing]())(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K]) {
```

When I delete the default value for `tree` in `WBTreeSet`, the code compiles.

I'm using Scala for the first time and I have already searched a lot of similar problems, however I still cannot resolve this issue. Is there any way to fix this without changing the structure of classes or should I do it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overloaded `apply` methods:

```
case class Node[K, V](key: K, value: Option[V] = None, left: Option[Node[K, V]] = None, right: Option[Node[K, V]] = None, size: Int = 1)(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])

case class Tree[K, V](root: Option[Node[K, V]] = None, alpha: Double = 0.25)(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])

case class WBTreeSet[K](tree: Tree[K, Nothing])(implicit ord: K => Ordered[K])
object WBTreeSet {
  def apply[K](implicit ord: K => Ordered[K]): WBTreeSet[K] = WBTreeSet(Tree[K, Nothing]())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you expect the implicit `ord` parameter of `WBTreeSet` to be passed to default value of `tree` parameter. Unfortunately, this will not work because in Scala, default parameter values cannot refer to other parameter values in the same parameter list or in subsequent parameter lists, e.g.

```
def thisWillWork(a: Int)(b: Int = a*2) = ???
def thisWillNotWork(a: Int, b: Int = a*2) = ???
def thisWillNotWork(a: Int = b*2)(b: Int) = ???
```

That, plus the fact that implicit parameters can only be passed in the last parameter list means that your `tree` param default value cannot access `ord` param.

How to work around this?

First, prefer using `Ordering` typeclass instead of implicit conversion to `Ordered`, e.g.

```
case class Node[K, V](...)(implicit ord: Ordering[K])
```

or shorter, using *context bound* syntax:

```
case class Node[K: Ordering, V](...)
```

Then, if you want to keep your default value, you probably have to use overloaded `apply` method instead of default parameter value:

```
case class WBTreeSet[K: Ordering](tree: Tree[K, Nothing])
object WBTreeSet {
  def apply[K: Ordering](): WBTreeSet[K] = WBTreeSet[K](Tree[K,Nothing]())
}
```